# Ideas, Tips, Tools, Framework for implementing Audit

Tags: c#, .net, database, audit, audit-trail

I'm looking for Ideas, Tips, Existing Frameworks (based on .NET), Tools and also your experience  on what's the best way to implement a good Audit Trail.

Our typical Applications are nothing fancy ASP.NET MVC 3- Security Layer - Business Layer - Data Access Layer - Database (SQL Server 2008)

My only requirement is that it has to be easy to implement and stored somehow in the Database.

Comment: Try [Audit.NET](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET) and its [extensions](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET#extensions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found some nice tools like [OmniAudit](http://www.krell-software.com/omniaudit/) etc, but not actually exactly was i was looking for. So i've decided to write my own Audit Trail Tool to generate and maintain Triggers.

Answer (score 2):

For auditing user actions, I had used [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html). While for auditing CRUD operations, triggers were used.

Here you could find some resource articles([Article1](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/auditlog.html), [Article2](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506085627/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/041807-1.shtml))  on implementing Audit log.

Comment: Triggers are not so easy to maintain in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using entity framework, please refer to: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ImplAudingTrailUsingEFP1.aspx